# Assigning elements from a for loop to another list

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

How would I get the elements iterated by a for loop to a list where I can print them out later in the my code? For example:

```
 for fname in dirlist:
    if fname.endswith(('.tgz','.tar')):
       print fname
```

fname only shows all the elements from dirlist only in the loop. I would like to view the elements at other areas in my code. I tried  li = fname ... but only one element shows up, when in fact there are about 7 elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
tarfiles = [fname for fname in dirlist if fname.endswith(('.tgz','.tar'))]
```

to print the filenames, use

```
print "\n".join(tarfiles)
```

or

```
for fname in tarfiles:
    print fname
```